# Fullpage.js not working when adding a new section

Tags: fullpage.js, section508

I was using with no problems fullpage.js when a strange thing happened. I add a section to my page (it was 4 slides, i added a new slide) and fullpage seems not to work anymore.

I tried this code https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/eNLBXo in a new page and even this doesn't work. This is the code i used to set up my page and online i can add a new section without problems. So i think the problem should be somewhere else.

```
<div id="enlabs">
        <div class="section testo">
            LUISS Enlabs è un ecosistema animato da una community in continua evoluzione, è il luogo ideale per trasformare ogni startup digitale in una realtà d’impresa, crea opportunità uniche per
            gli investitori. La capacità di avere una visione è il focus del nostro progetto. Con un approccio retrofuturistico abbiamo attinto da un repertorio di immagini che richiama gli anni ’50
            e ’60 del secolo scorso, un momento storico in cui grazie al boom economico e ai primi viaggi nello spazio si guardava con grande ottimismo alla tecnologia e al futuro.
        </div>


        <div class="section">
            <div class="slide fullscreen">
                <picture><source data-srcset="https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/2019/img_nuove/enlabs/SPST_enl_01_low.jpg" media="(max-width: 500px)"> <source data-srcset=
                "https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/2019/img_nuove/enlabs/SPST_enl_01_low.jpg" media="(max-width: 800px)"><img class="full-bleed-img lazyload" data-sizes="auto" data-src=
                "https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/2019/img_nuove/enlabs/SPST_enl_01_low.jpg"></picture>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="section">
            <div class="bordered" style="background-image:url(http://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/2019/img_nuove/cmp_img_017.jpg)">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="section">
            Four
        </div>


        <div class="section">
            Five
        </div>
    </div>
    <script async src='https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/lazysizes.min.js'>
    </script> 
    <script src='https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/easings.min.js'>
    </script> 
    <script src='https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/scrolloverflow.min.js'>
    </script> 
    <script src='https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/fullpage.js'>
    </script> 
    <script src='https://www.spazio.studio/wp-content/uploads/jquery-3.2.1.js'>
    </script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>





<script>
new fullpage('#enlabs', {
    anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5'],
    sectionsColor: ['white', 'white', '#FFF', '#ADD8E6', '#ADD8E6'],
    autoScrolling: true,
    css3: true,
    lazyLoading: true,
    scrollOverflow: false,
    lockAnchors: true,
});
</script>
```

I see page progress in navbar but browser window is white.

Comment: I made an attemp on codepen (https://codepen.io/antonio_senia/pen/PoYVdXy) and it seems to work. I don't know if is a compatibility issue with Semplice theme.

Comment: Your codepen works as expected.